# Never use pre-defined real types?

Tags: ada, safety-critical

I am starting to learn the Ada language by reading [ADA Distilled](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/docs/distilled/adadistilled.pdf).
In chapter 3.8 It says:

> The Ada programmer never uses pre-defined real types for
>   safety-critical, production quality software.

I was wondering what this really implies and what should I do instead of using pre-defined real types. Does this mean that I cannot use Integers?

Comment: Integers and real/floating point types are quite different things.  And I can't find any sensible excuse for using predefined floating point types (except that I am lazy).

Comment: One reason to avoid the predefined float types is that the LRM gives permission to the implementer to use/wrap IEEE754 -- this means that you'll have to deal with non-'normal' values (NaN, INF) manually and this can be rather surprising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what the author was thinking, and I wish he had explained it.  I personally *hate* rules handed down without any explanation, expecting readers to simply accept it as "received wisdom".  (Nothing against the author--I know he's a good guy.)

That said, here are my thoughts:

The first version of Ada, Ada 83, said that there were predefined `Integer` and `Float` types, and that implementations may provide other types like `Long_Integer` and `Long_Float`.  The language did not put any boundaries on implementations' definitions, though.  In theory, an implementation could provide an `Integer` type that was 2 bits wide, holding only values from -2 to +1.  (It would be bad for compiler sales, but would conform to the language definition.)  Because there was no guarantee that the predefined types would be large enough or (in the case of floats) precise enough to meet a program's needs, programmers were encouraged to always define their own integer and floating-point types that specified the desired range and precision.

Ada 95 added some constraints: `Integer` had to hold values at least in the range -32768..32767, and `Float` had to support 6 decimal digits of precision if the implementation supported floating-point numbers that precise.  So some of the motivation for avoiding the predefined types has gone away.  If your calculations are such that you don't ever need a precision more than 6 digits, then `Float` should be OK.  If `Float` is less precise than 6 digits, then the implementation can't support 6 digits at all, and you won't do any better by defining your own float.  So if you know you'll never need to migrate to a different compiler, you're probably OK.

Still, you could run into portability problems that don't occur with integer types.  If an `Integer` variable will never hold values outside the range -32768..32767, then you shouldn't encounter any problems moving from a machine with a 16-bit `Integer` type to another machine with a 24-bit `Integer` or a 32-bit `Integer` or whatever--the calculations should work the same.  But I can't say the same about floating-point numbers.  Floating-point rounding means that a program that behaves one way where `Float` is a 32-bit IEEE float could behave differently if moved to a machine where `Float` is a 64-bit IEEE float, or vice versa.  If you have a program and your 32-bit floats suddenly all change to 64-bit floats, it needs to be retested very thoroughly.  There's a decent chance something will break.

If you define your own floating-point type, though, you should be OK, at least if you confine the implementations to those that use IEEE floats.  (Which is most machines these days, although there may be a few VAXes still around that use their own floating-point format.  I wouldn't be surprised if there were still more than a few of those beasts still in use.)  If you need to migrate between an IEEE-float and a non-IEEE-float machine, then even writing your own floating-point definition might not be enough; the precision could be slightly different, and the results might not be exactly the same.

Comment: What if your compiler has `type Float is digits 12` and you really only need 6 significant digits?  Why not be explicit about what you need?  What is the benefit of using the predefined type?

Answer (score 2):

"Never" is too strong in my opinion.

"Never in safety critical software" is quite another thing, and opinions (especially mine) don't matter.

For non-critical code (most of my programming is non-critical, I use Ada simply because debugging C takes me too long) the pre-defined types are OK, but defining your own really doesn't take any time. [Possibly relevant Q&A...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457365/example-code-detailing-difference-in-typing-between-ada-and-java/30457875#30457875)

For learning Ada, use (play with) defining your own real and integer types just to see how it works. Especially for integer types, get used to the idea of special types for array indexes, to eliminate buffer overflows and bounds errors.

But while learning other aspects of the language, you can just use the pre-defined types for many purposes, to save effort and focus on what you're trying to learn.

However, if your Ada program could maim or kill someone, or lose large sums of money, then ignore the above and take the advice from "Ada Distilled".

Answer (score 1):

It means that you should "always"[*] define types matching your problem.

[*] If your problem includes processing strings, you are advised to use the standard `String` type for that (and `Positive` for indexing in it).  There are other similar exceptions, but unless you can explain why you should use a predefined type, don't.